# Sorting a table with combobox using tablesorter plugin

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm using the old tablesorter plugin.

In my table, I have a column of comboboxes which are sortable.
However, I can't get the comboboxes to sort properly when I change their values.

I have something like this (modified, excerpt):

```
function sortTable(columnId, sortOrder) {

    if (columnId && sortOrder) {
    // previous settings available

    var columnIndex = $("#" + columnId).index();

    // determine sort index
    var sortIndex = -1;
    if ("asc" == sortOrder) {
        sortIndex = 0;
    } else if ("desc" == sortOrder) {
        sortIndex = 1;
    }

    // sort table
    if (sortIndex > -1) {
        $('#table1').tablesorter({
            textExtraction: function(node) {
                // special processing for combobox
                if ($(node).find('option:selected').text() != "") {
                    var selected = $(node).find('option:selected').text();
                    return selected;
                } else {
                    return $(node).text();
                }
            },
            sortList: [[columnIndex, sortIndex]]
        });
    }
}  else {
    // no previous settings available

    $('#table1').tablesorter({
        textExtraction: function(node) {
            // special processing for combobox
            if ($(node).find('option:selected').text() != "") {
                var selected = $(node).find('option:selected').text();
                return selected;
            } else {
                return $(node).text();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This function is called when I click on a table header.

```
$("#table1 th").click(function() {
    var sortInfo = determineColumnIdToSort();
    var sortOrder = determineNewSortOrder();
    removeTablesorter(); // removes binds to the tableSorter
    sortAssignMeasuresTable(columnId, sortOrder);
});
```

My problem is:
If I have comboboxes with different values, they would sort properly when I click on the header. But if I change, select another value for the combobox, the sorting does not work properly. The combobox would remain in the same position, even though it should be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original version of tablesorter has a method to `updateCell`, but in this case it doesn't properly index the cell to update, so you'll need to trigger a full `update` which isn't very efficient in large tables. Hopefully you're at least using jQuery 1.7+, if you are then use this code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/472/)):

```
// Custom parser which returns the currently selected options
// updated dynamically using the "change" function below
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "select",
    is: function () {
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s, table, cell) {
        return $(cell).find('select').val() || s;
    },
    type: "text"
});

// update select in the tablesorter cache when the change event fires.
// This method only works with jQuery 1.7+
// you can change it to use delegate (v1.4.3+) or live (v1.3+) as desired
// if this code interferes somehow, target the specific table $('#mytable'),
// instead of $('table')
$(window).load(function () {
    // this flag prevents the update event from being spammed
    var alreadyUpdating = false;
    $('table').find('tbody').on('change', 'select', function (e) {
        if (!alreadyUpdating) {
            alreadyUpdating = true;
            $(this).trigger('update');
            setTimeout(function () {
                alreadyUpdating = false;
            }, 10);
        }
    });
});

$('table').tablesorter({
    headers: {
        1: {
            sorter: 'select'
        }
    }
});
```

If you are interested, I have [forked the original tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) and added parsers to update select, input & checkboxes. You can see these parsers in action in this [grouping rows widget demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-grouping.html).